# How to test a browser supported feature in React testing library (IntersectionObserver is not defined)

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test my App.js file with [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/) When I try to render the App component I always get this error `ReferenceError: IntersectionObserver is not defined`.

When I went through the code, I saw that the ScrollMenu component from the [React horizontal scrolling menu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-horizontal-scrolling-menu) library causes this issue as it only supports the browser level. I think this happens because React Testing Library uses node.js runtime.

What I can do to render and test the App component?

My App component

```
import { ScrollMenu } from 'react-horizontal-scrolling-menu';

<ScrollMenu>
  {data.map((item) => (
    <ComponentOne data={data} />
  ))}
</ScrollMenu>
```

My App test file

```
test('renders the app', () => {
  render(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <App />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
});
```